# field 'int count' in Java AbstracStringBuilder class is set in/by which method?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I understand StringBuffer uses the fields 'value' and 'count' which StringBuffer inherits from AbstractStringBuilder.  The constructor StringBuffer() for example calls on AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) to create a 16-Bit-array using super(16). So far so good for how to set 'value' but how or in which method is 'count' set/initialized/determined?

Answer (score 1):

`count` is initialized to 0, since it represents the number of characters contained in the `StringBuffer`. Appending characters to the `StringBuffer` increments the count.

For example, appending a single char increments the count by 1 :

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c) {
  int newCount = count + 1;
  if (newCount > value.length)
    expandCapacity(newCount);
  value[count++] = c; // count is incremented
  return this;
}
```